# Multiple base repositories in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am currently migrating an application that manages JPA in form of Hibernate ORM by itself to `Spring Boot 2.0.0` with `Spring Data JPA 2.0.0`. This application currently has about 50 entities, each with its own data source which I now want to migrate to Spring Data Repositories. Many of those data sources have many quite similar features, i.e. filtering with a custom filter class or fetching an entity by some sort of unique key that is not its id. I could very well just implement a custom base class as described in the [Spring Data JPA Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories), but this would mean that I would have to would have to provide custom filters for each and every entity, where I only need on for maybe 10 of them.

Is there any possible way to have Spring Data merge multiple custom repository implementations as shown below?

---

Entities:

```
@Entity
public class Artist {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    int secondaryId;
    String name;

    ... constructors, getter, setter, etc ...
}    

@Entity
public class Album {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    String name;

    ... constructors, getter, setter, etc ...
}
```

Custom repositories with default implementations:

```
public interface FilterRepository<T> {
    public T findByFilter(Filter<T> t);
}

public class FilterRepositoryImpl<T> implements AdditionalRepository<T> {
    public T findByFilter(Filter<T> t) {
        ... return something ...
    }
}

public interface FindByFieldRepository<T> {
    public T findByField(String fieldName, Object fieldValue);
}

public class FindByFieldRepositoryImpl<T> implements FindByFieldRepository<T> {
    public T findByField(String fieldName, Object fieldValue) {
        ... return something ...
    }
}
```

Spring Data Repositories

```
@Repository
public interface ArtistRepository extends JpaRepository<Artist, Integer>, 
        FilterRepository<Artist>, FindByFieldRepository<Artist> {
}

@Repository
public interface AlbumRepository extends JpaRepository<Album, Integer>, 
        FilterRepository<Album> {
}
```

Notice that `ArtistRepository` extends both custom repositories while `AlbumRepository` only extends `FilterRepository`. Another repository might extend `JpaRepository` but none of the custom defined ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be possible with two interfaces and a single custom repository implementation. For example:

> **Step 1**: Simple extension of `JpaRepository`

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface FilteringJpaRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
  T findByFilter(Filter<T> t);
}
```

> **Step 2**: A more complicated extension of `JpaRepository`

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ExtendedJpaRepository<T> extends FilteringJpaRepository<T> {
  T findByField(String fieldName, Object fieldValue);
}
```

> **Step 3**: A custom repository implementation

Add a custom repository implementation as described in the documentation linked to in the question. Also make sure to change the JPA configuration to use the custom implementation.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public class ExtendedJpaRepositoryImpl<T>
             extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, Long>
             implements ExtendedJpaRepository<T> {
  ...

  public T findByFilter(Filter<T> t) { ... }

  public T findByField(String fieldName, Object fieldValue) { ... }
}
```

> **Step 4**: Extend from the appropriate repository as required

```
public interface AlbumRepository extends FilteringJpaRepository<Album> {}

public interface ArtistRepository extends ExtendedJpaRepository<Artist> {}
```

Since the functional repositories extend only the required repository, their consumers will only see methods appropriate for them.

---

Please see the [sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/42781264) for this approach.

Comment: While this is not the prettiest solution I could have thought of it is certainly one the should work. The only "problem" I still have, is that I have not only two custom repositories, but about 5 or 6 (or more in the future) which I cannot put into any hierarchy and one class that implements all of these interfaces is kind of ugly.

Comment: Hi, I have the same set-up with my repositories, whereby I have a base repository (annotated with @NoRepositoryBean) which extends Spring's CrudRepository, and I have individual repository interfaces which extend my base repository. One issue I have found is that in my database, all my entity classes data are all in each entity table - and I'm trying to find out if this has anything to do with it.